# Does an IO exception get thrown if the disk is full?

Tags: c#, .net

What exception is thrown in the .NET Framework when trying to write a file but the disk is full?

Does Windows buffer file writes?

Comment: Why don't you try it and see - plug in a usb stick and keep writing junk to it until you run out of space and see what happens. I suspect that you'll get a managed `IOException` on the write that will take it over the limit, as the buffering process should be opaque to managed code.

Comment: C# is a programming language - it doesn't do anything because of file system full. You mean "Does an IO exception in .NET get thrown..."

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You will get an IO exception:

```
System.IO.IOException: There is not enough space on the disk.
at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
```

The `System.IO` library handles the actual tasks of reading and writing to disk and wraps them in managed code, so you shouldn't get any unmanaged exceptions using them.

It's also worth trying this (with one of those shoddy small USB sticks they give out everywhere) to see what happens with your code - that's usually the best way of finding out this sort of thing.

Comment: I d also like to know the answer to exactly WHEN the exception will get thrown

Comment: The exception will be thrown when you attempt a write operation (or to open a file for writing, I think) on a full disk. Read operations on a full disk won't throw the exception.

Answer (score 2):

You will get an 'IOException'. But the problem is that 'IOException' is quite broad spectrum, not only disk full. I recommend to also check the 'HResult' inside to precisely filter out this case.

```
                catch (IOException ioEx)
                {
                    // Is it 'DISK_FULL'?
                    uint unsignedResult = (uint)ioEx.HResult;
                    if (unsignedResult.IsOneOf(0x80000027, 0x80000070, 0x80070027, 0x80070070))
                    {
                        // Remove the partial file
                        try
                        {
                            File.Delete(pathName);
                        }
                        catch { }
                        // do your special stuff here
                    }
                    else
                        throw;
                }
```

Note that the Win32 error codes from region 8000 are mirrored in the region 8007, thats why there is a near duplicate in the checks.

Answer (score 0):

You could check the Win 32 Exception after what you have fails to see if that gives more detail:

```
     Win32Exception ex = new Win32Exception();
     string low_level_error = ex.Message;
```

How are you writing to disk? For [FileStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream(VS.80).aspx) it says:

> "Be sure to call the Dispose method on
>   all FileStream objects, especially in
>   environments with limited disk space.
>   Performing IO operations can raise an
>   exception if there is no disk space
>   available and the Dispose method is
>   not called before the FileStream is
>   finalized."

Answer (score 0):

Not a direct answer to the question, but I had a situation where I had to differentiate whether an IOException was caused by "not enough space on disk" or "file already open/in-use" (the latter being the expected/common outcome), and this question was the closest thing I could find to do it. I'm not a fan of the proposed answer using magic hex error codes, which I'm not even sure would work outside of Windows since the error codes relate to Win32 errors. Simply knowing it's caused by an IOException is not sufficient for my use case, since I need to handle other types of IOExceptions in the same try-catch.

Here's what I did instead: make use of [System.IO.DriveInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.driveinfo?view=net-7.0) to validate the available space in the drive, this could either be done before your write altogether, or within the IOException catch, to confirm whether the IOException was caused by the drive being full, or something else. In my case, full disks should be a rare occurence, so I only put that check within the exception catch.

You can pass a full absolute path to the DriveInfo constructor, which makes it easy to initialize without extracting the drive from your path or anything like that: `new DriveInfo(absolutePath).AvailableFreeSpace`

```
catch (IOException)
{
        // absolutePath: the path we're attempting to write to
        // memStreamArr: byte[] being written to the file
        if (new DriveInfo(absolutePath).AvailableFreeSpace < memStreamArr.Length)
        {
            // code to execute when disk full...
        }
        else
        {
            // code to execute on IOExceptions that aren't disk full...
        }
}
```

Hope this can help anyone in a similar situation. What you compare AvailableFreeSpace to will depend on context, you might not have the exact length of bytes you were writing within the catch exception. For example if the memStreamArr was going to be passed to a GZipStream, then it would result in less bytes. I don't think this is really an issue unless you are dealing with massive files. In my case I am writing many small files to standard desktop drives, so if you have 2MB or 3MB of storage left, that's basically too full to keep using the program regardless (so it doesn't hurt to over-estimate).